# Looking for more elegant task processing solutions

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm working on tasks processing solution. The task source is SQLlite DB with thousands of records. Each task is http request, so it can take a few seconds to finish. I decide to use asyncio for processing. Examples are based on small task queue, so use them "as is" very memory consuming and takes a lot of time to fill tasks list. 
In the documentation, it looks something like this

```
    tasks = []
    for i in range(1,10):
            task = asyncio.create_task(worker(i))
            tasks.append(task)


     await asyncio.gather(tasks)
```

What I want to do is to read tasks from DB one by one and process them keeping concurrency in limits of MAX_CONCURRENT
So, here is my dirty hack, but I believe there is a more elegant solution for this.

**UPD**
An hour in the morning is worth two in the evening :)
But anyway, I think the use of Semaphore will be better, but I'm not sure how to use it in the loop

```py
import random
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession

from sqlitedict import SqliteDict

async def testWorker (id,url, db):
    #placeholder url processing
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))


async def main():

    MAX_CONCURRENT = 5
    db = SqliteDict('./taskdb.sqlite', autocommit=True)

    tasks = set()
    it = db.iteritems()
    while True:
        try:
            id, url = next(it)

            if (len(tasks) < MAX_CONCURRENT):
                task = asyncio.create_task(testTask(id,url, db))
                tasks.add(task)
            else:
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks,return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                tasks = pending

        except StopIteration:              
            break

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, the most idiomatic way is to use a [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore). In that case your loop becomes much much simpler, as it no longer needs to enforce `MAX_CONCURRENT`, it's all done by the semaphore:

```
async def testWorker(id,url, db, semaphore):
    # async with ensures that no more than MAX_CONCURRENT
    # workers enter the block at the same time
    async with semaphore:
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))

async def main():
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT)
    db = SqliteDict('./taskdb.sqlite', autocommit=True)

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        coros = [testTask(id, url, db, semaphore)
                 for id, url in db.iteritems()]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Another option is to start a fixed number of workers and communicate with them via a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html). This is slightly more complex, but it's a good option for when the number of tasks is potentially huge or unbounded.

```
async def testWorker(db, queue):
    while True:
        id, url = queue.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
        queue.task_done()

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(db, queue)]
    db = SqliteDict('./taskdb.sqlite', autocommit=True)

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for id, url in db.iteritems():
            await queue.put((id, url))
        await queue.join()

    # cancel the workers, which are now sitting idly
    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a great solution. The example with semaphore is the best, but it's required to fill the task list before gathering. As I understand, it's possible just to add semaphore to the second example to achieve maximum workers. Something like that

```python
async def testWorker (db, queue,semaphore):
    while True:
       async with semaphore:
          id, url = queue.get()
          await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
          queue.task_done()
```

Comment: @TimRulanov The semaphore allows to fill the task list before gathering, in fact that's precisely what the first code snippet does. Adding a semaphore to the second solution makes no sense, as the architecture of that code already ensures the maximum number of workers.